# odoo, how can I add internal reference to quotation report?

Tags: odoo

I need to add the internal reference `default_code` to the quotation report `sale_report_template.xml`.

I tried using

```html
   <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.default_code"/></td>
```

but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: The internal reference of products in your quotation? Cause the internal reference of a product is part of it's display name, which is printed in quotation report by default.

Comment: Maybe you could try `l.product_id.default_code` instead of `l.default_code`. Without errors I am not sure. Please add error logs.

Comment: thanks for your help. plz add it as an answer in order to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
 <t t-foreach="layout_category['lines']" t-as="l">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span t-field="l.product_id.default_code"/></td>
```